# How angularjs $watchCollection method keep the oldCollection reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have an 'Add Item' button on the screen which adds a new item to a list when it's clicked.

I use `$scope.$watchCollection` to watch a function which returns a list of all visible items.

When I clicked the 'add item' button, I received unlimited digest loop error.
It seems that $watchCollection clones the list, and then the newCollection is alwasy not equle the oldCollection.

JS Bin Demo:
https://jsbin.com/mavolecipu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
function MainController($scope) {
        var ctrl = this;
        var _index = 1;
        var _visibleItems = [];
        var _allItems = [];



        ctrl.addItem = addItem;
        ctrl.visibleItems = [];


        $scope.$watchCollection(getVisibleItem, function (newVal, oldVal) {
          // it looks like the newVal is always not equal oldVal?? 
          if(newVal!== oldVal){
               ctrl.visibleItems = newVal;
           }

        });


        function addItem() {

            _allItems.push({
                index: _index,
                isVisible: true
            });


            _index = _index+1;

        }


        function getVisibleItem() {
            var newVisibleItems = _(_allItems).filter({isVisible: true}).value();

            // use same reference
            _visibleItems.length = 0;

            _.merge(_visibleItems, newVisibleItems);

            return _visibleItems;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that every time a digest cycle runs, `getVisibleItem` is called.  That function clears `_visibleItems` and then adds everything back to it via `_.merge`.  Because `_.merge` makes deep copies of the items (thus causing them to be different references), it triggers `$watchCollection`, which will include another digest cycle being fired, causing an infinite loop of digest cycles.

Rather than clearing `_visibleItems` and then adding items back into it, I recommend you do the work of actually adding/removing items that have had their visibility changed (i.e. remove items in `_visibleItems` that have `isVisible=false` and add in items that are only in `_allItems` with `isVisible=true`.

Alternately, replacing `_.merge(_visibleItems, newVisibleItems)` with a simple for-loop or `[].push.apply(_visibleItems, newVisibleItems` will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see. The lodash merge is a deep copy which alwasy create new items and copy values into it.